# Как сохранять в коде изменения при перезапуске страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В примере 3 "div" при нажатии меняют цвет. Вопрос как сделать так чтобы это все сохранялось и при перезагрузке страницы изменения сохранялись. Например зашел пользователь пощелкал остановился на втором. Вышел на следующий день зашел на сайт а активный див остался тот же что он щелкнул последний раз.

Буду рад даже литературе в этом направлении. Заранее спасибо=)

```js
$('.toggler').click(function () {
          $('.toggler').removeClass('toggler_active');

          var toggler = $(this);
          toggler.addClass('toggler_active');
                  });
```

```css
.toggler {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  }
.toggler_active {
background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggler toggler_active'></div>
<div class='toggler'></div>
<div class='toggler'></div>
```

Comment: либо хранить куки с настройками, либо как ответили в `localStorage`. В первом варианте корректный html сгенерите прямо на сервере и выдадите клиенту, во втором сервер выдает какой то общий вид, а на клиенте скриптами корректируется. Поэтому могут быть некоторые визуальные неудобства, типа сначала див загружается с белым фоном, а потом становится красным. имхо, куки оптимальней.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас на сайте нет процедуры регистрации и возможности хранить эту информацию на сервере, то можно посоветовать вам использовать localStorage для хранения этой информации в браузере пользователя, например:

Записываем выбор:

```
localStorage.setItem('squareNumber', '2');
```

При загрузке страницы считываем предыдущий выбор:

```
var squareNumber = localStorage.getItem('squareNumber');
```

Естественно, это будет работать только если пользователь будет заходить с одного и того же компьютера.

Comment: А если привязывать к пользователю через его логин это работает?

Comment: Если пользователь логинится у вас на сайте, значит вы можете хранить на сервере информацию о пользователе (логин, пароль и номер выбранного квадратика). После авторизации пользователя генерите нужную вам разметку страницы используя эту информацию. Для этого localStorage не нужен.